# Insert Content Before div#main from the functions.php File

Tags: functions, filters, hooks, actions, the-content

I know WordPress has a filter for targeting the content in the functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'the_content')
```

However, is there a filter to insert content BEFORE ? 'the_content' filter puts content AFTER div#main. I'm looking for something like:

```
add_filter( 'before_main')
```

Does a filter like that exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The markup surrounding the content is not specified by WordPress, so there is no hook for that.

But you can declare your own hook there. In your template file, write …

```
<?php
do_action( 'before_content_container' );
?>
<div class="main">
    <?php
    the_content();
    ?>
</div>
<?php
do_action( 'after_content_container' );
?>
```

… and then you can register a callback for that action in your `functions.php`.